# adding array name property to JSON object [ES5]

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-5

I have a JSON object with this structure:

```
{"Firstname":"john","Lastname":"doe"}
```

How do it change it to an array with this structure with the name 'abc'(?):

```
users: [{"Firstname":"john","Lastname":"doe"}]
```

This is I'm building my object from input values:

```
var obj = {};
obj.Firstname = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
obj.Lastname = document.getElementById("surname").value;
 console.log(obj);
var jsonStringObj = JSON.stringify(obj);
 console.log(jsonStringObj );
```

which returns:

```
{"Firstname":"john","Lastname":"doe"}
```

thanks!

Comment: i do not understand, what you are trying to achieve and what fails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create new array and push the entire object.

```js
var x = {"Firstname":"john","Lastname":"doe"};
var newArray = [];
newArray.push(x);

console.log([{"Firstname":"john","Lastname":"doe"}])
```

Comment: Thank you!!! how do I add a name property to e.i users: [{"Firstname":"john","Lastname":"doe"}]  thanks!!

Comment: what is your desire output ? can you update that in your question

Comment: the output should be >      users: [{"Firstname":"john","Lastname":"doe"}]

Comment: try this @fosowe    var newobj={"users":newArray};
console.log(newobj);

Comment: You do not need to push x into the array, you can create the array with x in it, like ```var newArray = [x];```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object, having a key of user and a value of an array, having your item:

```
var jsonStringObj = {user: [JSON.stringify(obj)]};
```